# Python data correlation

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between the **pearson correlation method** and the normal **corr()** method? I expect it to be the same output, is that right?

Comment: If you are referring to ```pandas.corr()``` - then indeed Pearson is the default one: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

Comment: The Pandas 0.25.3 documentation says that pearson is default.

Comment: Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no difference, if method='pearson'

Comment: That should be more a comment, than answer.